# list to pandas dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following list:

```
list = [-0.14626096918979603,
 0.017925919395027533,
 0.41265398151061766]
```

I have created a `pandas` `dataframe` using the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list, index=['var1','var2','var3'], columns=['Col1'])
df
               Col1
var1         -0.146261
var2         0.017926
var3         0.412654
```

Now I have a new list:

```
list2 = [-0.14626096918979603,
 0.017925919395027533,
 0.41265398151061766,
 -0.8538301985671065,
 0.08182534201640915,
 0.40291331836021105]
```

I would like to arrange the `dataframe` in a way that the output looks like this (MANUAL EDIT)

```
               Col1            Col2
var1         -0.146261   -0.8538301985671065
var2         0.017926   0.08182534201640915
var3         0.412654   0.40291331836021105
```

and that whenever there is a third or foruth colum... the data gets arranged in the same way. I have tried to convert the list to a `dict` but since I am new with python I am not getting the desired output but only errors due to invalid shapes.

-- EDIT --

Once I have the dataframe created, I want to plot it using `df.plot()`. However, the way the data is shown is not what I would like. I am comming from `R` so I am not sure if this is because of the data structure used in the `dataframe`. Is is it that I need one measurement in each row?

[image]

My idea would be to have the `col1`, `col2`, `col3` in the x-axis (it's a temporal series). In the y-axis the range of values (so that is ok in that plot) and the differnet lines should be showing the evolution of `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, etc.

Comment: Is your `list2` deliberatly longer than the first column of your DataFrame or is that final output just a slice from the actual output?

Comment: Just edited the question, I put the wrong `list2`.`list2` will be any multiple of 3 so its `len` would be 3,6,9.... The number or `rows` in `df` should be always 3 and data should be "split" in the columns. Hope its clear

Comment: why dont you remove the element which are common in list(please use diff name) and list2.. like `list2 = [i for i in list2 if  i not in list] then df['Col2'] = list2`

Comment: @iamklaus when working with the data it happens that I will not have `list` to compare with but `list2` will be produce directly. I started testing the converstion from `list` to `df` and now would like to move to the real case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could run something like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])

n_cols = int(np.ceil(len(list2) / len(df)))
for ii in range(n_cols):
    L = list2[ii * len(df) : (ii + 1) * len(df)]
    df['col_{}'.format(ii)] = L
```

if the length of your list is not multiple of the length of the dataframe (`len(list2) % len(df) != 0`, you should extend L (in the last loop) with `len(df) - (len(list2) % len(df))` NaN values

to answer the **second question,** should be sufficient to run

```py
df.T.plot()
```

for the **third question,** then it's a matter of how was originally designed the dataframe.
You could edit the code we wrote at the beginning to invert rows and columns

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
n_rows = int(np.ceil(len(list2) / len(df.columns)))
for ii in range(n_rows):
    L = list2[ii * len(df.columns) : (ii + 1) * len(df.columns)]
    df.loc['col_{}'.format(ii)] = L
```

but once you created the dataframe with the first designed way, there's nothing wrong in running

```py
df = df.T
```

Comment: nice it also works. I am just a little bit lost with  your code. Trying to understand what it actually does I am getting lost (since I am kind of new in python). Could you please explain a little bit the last two lines?

Comment: sure: the line before the last picks a subset of your list, depending on the for loop in which you are. So let's say, at the first loop will take the elements in the list from index 0 to the length of the dataframe, so, in this case, the first 3 elements. Then ii increases and it will take the elements from 3 to 2 times the length of the list, meaning the next 3 elements and so on.
The last line just assigns for every loop, the corresponding subset list of 3 elements to a new column that will be named 'col_' and then the number of the loop (ii).

Comment: Many thanks now its clear. Btw, just a curiosity: why using `ii` instead of `i`. Is that some kind of standard or just personal preference?

Comment: fair question :) It's just a personal preference, I don't even know if it is actually a good use (in case not, I apologize for being misleading). Let's say I have a list `x`, I usually like to iterate its elements with a for loop like `for xx in x:`, so in case of big loops I can easily recover from where it comes from. Plus, I can immediately recognize it as a variable that will change its value in the different iteration of the loop. But again, it's just a personal thing

Comment: I have edited the question to add an small issue I have while plotting the `dataframe`

Comment: I don't know if I totally got what you mean to plot. Pandas plots by default the index on the `x`, and the Series from each column as `y` with different colors for each series. If I understood correctly, you'd like to plot the contrary, then you can try `df.T.plot()` that will first transpose the dataframe (.T) and then plot. Otherwise you can use the classic matplotlib.pyplot.plot and specify directly x and y.

Comment: Well actually `df.T.plot()` works just fine, but wouldn't it be "better" to create the `dataframe` with the right structure so that `df.plot` reads it properly?

Comment: To reply I edited the first answer, so that the code is a bit more clear

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with. You can easily generalise it to more cols/rows by dynamically setting the shape

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np_list = np.array(list2)
list_prep = np.transpose(np_list.reshape(2, 3))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_prep, index=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], columns=['c1', 'c2'])
```

And the end result looks like this:

```
          c1        c2
v1 -0.146261 -0.853830
v2  0.017926  0.081825
v3  0.412654  0.402913
```

Comment: thanks. Just for the others who may be interested, I am planing to make it dynamic by using `index=[('v1', 'v2', 'v3')*n_rows]`, where `n_rows` is a `int` parameter that will scale the number of rows. For `columns`, not sure yet as I would need something to create new colums named `c1`, `c2`, `c3` etc. Basically if `list` contains 9 values, I would need 3 columns, if it contains 12 then 4 columns etc.

Comment: My answer covers this automatic naming of columns.

Comment: @ArnoMaeckelberghe Just saw it, I am gonna give it a try right now thanks

Comment: @Artem Vovsia, I have edited the question to add an small issue I have while plotting the `dataframe`

Answer (score 2):

To also automatically name the columns depending on the number of columns that will be created you could:

```
from numpy import array
from pandas import DataFrame

rows = 3
cols = int(len(list2) / rows)

data = DataFrame(array(list2).reshape(cols, rows).T)
data.columns = ['Col{}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(cols)]
data.index = ['var{}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(rows)]
```

**Output:**

```
          Col1      Col2
var1 -0.146261 -0.853830
var2  0.017926  0.081825
var3  0.412654  0.402913
```

This involves less hard-coding of the number of columns / names of columns.

Your edited question about plotting is something completely else, but here goes anyway:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(data.columns, data.T)
plt.legend(data.index)
plt.show()
```

Your plot should look better since you have more data, but the example data only had two columns:

[image: plot]

Comment: I think you mean `math.ceil` instead of `int` - because `int(7/3)` would give you 2 columns while OP would probably want 3 columns

Comment: OP clarified in a comment on his question that: "list2 will be any multiple of 3 so its len would be 3,6,9.... The number or rows in df should be always 3". For that reason I didn't bother importing another package.

Comment: @ArnoMaeckelberghe nice trick for the column. However, I see a problem with this option, If you check the order of the values in the `data` is not as it is supposed to be. Correct order can be seen in my question and also in @artem Vovsia answer. Maybe a combination of both answers, one to do the trick for naming the column and the other to get the data in the correct other would work?

Comment: @GCGM good observation, changed my example to give the correct output now

Comment: @ArnoMaeckelberghe , I have edited the question to add an small issue I have while plotting the `dataframe`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame({ 'a': list1, 'b': list2 })
          a         b
0 -0.146261 -0.146261
1  0.017926  0.017926
2  0.412654  0.412654
>>>
```

Note: Please be ensure that you equal no.of items in list1 and list2.